# Node JS read file insert to mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, filereader

I have a text file with this content

```
title: A, alert: notice, desc: Starting
title: B, alert: notice, desc: Process Step 1 and 2
 Step 1 - Execute
 Step 2 - Log
title: C, alert: notice, desc: "Ending"
```

I want to insert it to my mongo db with this format

```
{
 title: A,
 alert: notice,
 desc: Starting
},
{
 title: B,
 alert: notice,
 desc: Process Step 1 and 2 Step 1 - Execute Step 2 - Log
},
{
 title: C,
 alert: notice,
 desc: Ending
},
```

I've been trying to find node packages that could help but almost all file reader packages can only read the file and not allow line by line editing.
For example if the next line is indented it should merge with previous line.

Comment: I think you need to write some code to analyse the text data and restructure it into json as per your specification.

Comment: @VinceBowdrendo you know any module that could help analyze the text file and allow per line editing?

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require('readline');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let readline = [];
let readlinesplit = [];
let finalarrobj = [];
let keyarr = [
  'variable',
  'identification',
  'value',
  'unit',
  'status',
  'date',
  'time'
];
let splitline = [];
let filenamearr = []
let getfile;
let scSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    variable: {
      type : String
    },
    identification: {
      type : String
    },
    value: {
      type : String
    },
    unit: {

    },
    status: {
      type : String 
    },
    date: {
      type: Date
    },
    time: {
      type: Date
    }  
  }
)
const SC = mongoose.model('SC', scSchema);

try {
  fs.readdir('D:/scnner_data/public', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    data.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.match(/SC/)) {
        filenamearr.push(element);
      }
    });
    filenamearr.map(async (element) => {
      getfile = fs.createReadStream(`public/${element}`);
      readline = rl.createInterface({
        input: getfile,
        crlfDelay: Infinity 
      });
      for await (let line of readline) {
        splitline.push(line.split('\n'));
      };
      splitline.forEach((element) => {
        readlinesplit.push(element[0].split(';'));
      });
      for (let i = 0; i < readlinesplit.length; i++) {
        readobj = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < keyarr.length; j++) {
          readobj[keyarr[j]] = readlinesplit[i][j];
        };
        finalarrobj.push(readobj);
      };
      try {
        SC.insertMany(finalarrobj);
        console.log('data inserted for SC');
      } catch (error) {
        throw  error.message;
      }
    });
  })
} catch(e) {
   throw e.message
}
```

you can use this approach to read your directory and store data
this is just a basic approach to insert data from text file to databse.
i hopw this may help you

Answer (score -1):

This will be a two step process. The first will be parsing your file. It doesn't appear to be in any common standard (that I'm aware of) so you'll likely need to write this yourself.

The second part will be writing files to a mongodb. This is a separate issue, though if you follow the documentation it's fairly straightforward. I'd suggest you try these things and then ask again if you have any problems.

Edit:
Here's the file parsed to a js object: https://jsfiddle.net/cyksd7o3/

```js
var fileInput = 'title: A, alert: notice, desc: Starting\ntitle: B, alert: notice, desc: Process Step 1 and 2  Step 1 - Execute Step 2 - Log \ntitle: C, alert: notice, desc: "Ending"';

var parseFile = function(input){
  var rows = input.split('\n');
    var returnObj = [];
    for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
      var currRow = rows[i];
        returnObj.push(getDataObject(currRow));
    }
    return returnObj;
};

var getDataObject = function(inputRowString){
  var newObject = {};
  var propSplit = inputRowString.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < propSplit.length; i++){
      var currSplit = propSplit[i];
        var keyValue = currSplit.split(':');
        newObject[keyValue[0].replace(/\s/g,'')] = keyValue[1];
    }
    return newObject;
};

console.dir(parseFile(fileInput));
```

Comment: this code only works if each line is a new object to be inserted to mongo db... But as seen in the example text file that I have there two lines (Step 1 - Execute
 Step 2 - Log) 
that should be part of the second object

if I use your code it would result to an error because it would read the 3rd and 4th line as new objects

Comment: @JuanCarlosCabotaje  perhaps you could give some idea about how you'd like to separate the rows of data, in that case?